# Mailing address required for filing I-539

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, covid-19, mail

My Parents are stuck in US due to COVID 19. They are on B2 visa and their authorized stay as per I-94 is expiring on April 21, 2020. We are in the process of filing I-539 for extending their stay.

If I go through online process then I need to submit individual applications for my mum and dad separately and so fees for both need to be paid separately. i.e. $370+$85/member.
But if I mail I-539 then we can apply with co-applicant and fees need to be paid for single applicant i.e. total of $370+$170.
This seems to be very economical to us and so going via mail process.
But I am not able to figure out exact mailing address as there are offices in different locations and accepting different categories of forms.

Can someone help me with the exact mailing address for I-539 form. I am currently residing in Alabama state.

Thanks,
Jugal

Answer (score 5):

USCIS publishes the correct [I-539 mailing addresses](https://www.uscis.gov/i-539-addresses) on their web site.

Here you will find many addresses, the correct one depends on the immigration status you are applying to change or extend. Because none of the special addresses apply to you, you should use the last set of addresses, for "All other Forms I-539":

> **USCIS Dallas Lockbox**
>
> For U.S. Postal Service (USPS):
>
> USCIS
> P.O. Box 660166
> Dallas, TX 75266
>
> For FedEx, UPS, and DHL deliveries:
>
> USCIS
> ATTN: I-539
> 2501 S. State Highway 121 Business
> Suite 400
> Lewisville, TX 75067

Comment: You should also consider including a [Form G-1145](https://www.uscis.gov/g-1145) with your application package, so that you will get an acknowledgement of receipt by email or text message. There is no additional fee for this.

Comment: you should include that in your answer to be sure the OP see it